# Baldurs Gate 2 for iPad - Quick Spells

Tags: ios, baldurs-gate-2

I can't figure out how to assign spells to the quick spell slots.

I tried to "long press" on the empty quick spell slot, then tap on the spell, but no dice.

Comment: trivial question, is that game in ipad worth its cost? what do you think?

Comment: Dude yes! But first play through bg1. The game doesn't have a timer but I would estimate more than 20 hours to beat